# Splitting a list to sublists with sizes given in another list

Tags: python, list

I have these lists:

```
l1 = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]
l2 = [1,3,2,3]
```

How can I split `l1` this way?

```
[[a],[b,c,d],[e,f],[g,h,i]]

-The first element is a list of one element because of the 1 of l2
-The second element is a list of three elements because of the 3 of l2
-The third element is a list of two elements because of the 2 of l2
-The fourth element is a list of three elements because of the 3 of l2
```

I've tried using a function:

```
def divide(num, n):
        return [num[i*n : (i+1)*n] for i in range(len(num)//n)]  

x = divide(l2,1)
for i in range(len(l2)):
    z = x[i]
    divide(l1,z)
```

But it's not working...

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this ? It's more like do it for me question

Comment: [`more_itertools.split_into`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.split_into) can do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Code

```
l1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
l2 = [1,3,2,3]

start = 0
l = []
for i in l2:
    l.append(l1[start: start+i])
    start = start + i
print(l)
```

## Output

```
[['a'], ['b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
[[l1.pop(0) for x in range(i)] for i in l2]
```

Output

```
[['a'], ['b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Work with an explicit iterator and `itertools.islice`.

```
>>> l1 = list("abcdefghi")
>>> l2 = [1,3,2,3]
>>> itr = iter(l1)
>>> [list(islice(itr, None, x)) for x in l2]
[['a'], ['b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

Using `itr` instead of `l1` means that `islice` won't start reading from the beginning of `l1` on each call.

You can use `functools.partial` to refactor this to make the list comprehension a little more readable:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> take = partial(islice, iter(l1), None)
>>> [list(take(x)) for x in l2]
[['a'], ['b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do it like this =

```
start = 0
sublists = []
for n in l2:
   to = start + n
   sublists.append(l1[start:to])
   start = to
```

Result is your desired list

Answer (score 0):

Using `enumerate` with `slicing` ,  you can do it this way :

```
l1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
l2 = [1,3,2,3]

for index, num in enumerate(l2):
  sum_up = sum(l2[:index])
  print(l1[sum_up:sum_up+num])
```